# How to fill an array with object containing ascending stringified numbers?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to generate an object array which has three keys with string values from 1 to 31. The strings should have two characters, which means 1-9 should get a 0 in front.

```
const days = [
  { key: '01', value: '01', text: '01' },
  { key: '02', value: '02', text: '02' },
  { key: '03', value: '03', text: '03' },
  ...
  { key: '30', value: '30', text: '30' },
  { key: '31', value: '31', text: '31' }
]
```

I think it should be done a bit shorter and smarter, then the solution which I came up with:

```
const days = Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, k) => {
  return { 
    key: k > 10 ? (k + 1).toString() : '0' + (k + 1),
    value: k > 10 ? (k + 1).toString() : '0' + (k + 1),
    text: k > 10 ? (k + 1).toString() : '0' + (k + 1)
  }
})
```

And what to do if I don't start at value 1? For example the same array for the years from 1950 until now (in reverse order):

```
const years = [
  { key: '2018', value: '2018', text: '2018' },
  ...
  { key: '1950', value: '1950', text: '1950' }
]
```

Comment: What's the question? Does something not work? If so, what?

Comment: @Pointy I don't know how to do this for `years` as it doesn't start with `1`. And I hope it could be done a bit shorter...

Comment: Maybe just don't add 1 to `k`? It's really not clear what your question is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make it simple, you can use `padStart()`

```js
const days = Array.from({length: 31}, (v, k) => {
  let o = (k + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
  return {key: o,value: o,text: o}
});

console.log(days);
```

Regarding the year, the same structure but instead of adding 1, add the start year.

```js
const years = Array.from({length: 20}, (v, k) => {
  let o = (k + 2000);
  return {key: o,value: o,text: o}
});

console.log(years);
```

Doc: [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

Comment: Wow. Did not know about padstart, but unfortunately is not supported by IE

Comment: Yeah, currently, this not supported by IE :) But this nice for server side JS like node

Comment: @user3142695 - You can polyfill it for IE.

Comment: And if you want an IE supported, You might want to use loop instead of `Array.from` because that is not also supported (i think)

Comment: @Eddie - Quite true, though it can also be polyfilled. IE doesn't support arrow functions either, and they *can't* be polyfilled (but can be transpiled). :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I think it should be done a bit shorter and smarter...

Well, you can certainly repeat yourself a lot less:

```
const days = Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, k) => {
  const value = k > 10 ? (k + 1).toString() : '0' + (k + 1);
  return { 
    key: value,
    value,
    text: value
  };
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const days = Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, k) => {
  const value = k > 10 ? (k + 1).toString() : '0' + (k + 1);
  return { 
    key: value,
    value,
    text: value
  };
});
console.log(days);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

> And what to do if I don't start at value 1?

Just add in the value you want:

```
const startYear = 2018;
const years = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (v, k) => {
  const value = String(k + startYear);
  return { 
    key: value,
    value,
    text: value
  };
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const startYear = 2018;
const years = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (v, k) => {
  const value = String(k + startYear);
  return { 
    key: value,
    value,
    text: value
  };
});
console.log(years);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Naturally, wrap that in a function if you need something reusable.

Comment: The year should be descending: From current year 70 values down

Comment: @user3142695 - Simple enough: Subtract rather than adding. I'm sure you can adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const days = Array.from({ length: 31 }, (v, i) => 
  ({ key: v = (++i > 9 ? '' : '0') + i, value: v, text: v }) );

const years = Array.from({ length: 2018 - 1950 + 1 }, (v, i) => 
  ({ key: v = 2018 - i + '', value: v, text: v }) );

console.log( JSON.stringify( days  ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
console.log( JSON.stringify( years ).replace(/},/g, '},\n ') );
```